# Google Currents styled Slide show

Tags: android, slideshow

I came across Google Currents and i absolutely love the UI. 
Is there any plugin or implementation library to achieve the Slide show on the homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock will be your new friend with the ViewPagerIndicaotor!:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: You are talking about the bottom slide for the icons? Your question is not so well described, si I guessed you were talking about that one. Please add more information, so I can understand what you are talking about and what you want to achieve!